# Pushing elems into an array conditionally

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a simple array with a few elems & a new elem , trying to check the elems with a function , push the new elem into the array if not already present & ignore it if it is.

I created a function with an if /else statement but the code always adds the new item to the array.

```
var arr=['a','b'];
var newElem='c';
function f(){
   for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
     if(arr[i] == newElem){ console.log('Exists');return }
     else {arr.push(newElem);console.log(arr); return }
   }
}
f();
```

The code works fine if the new item not present in the array but if it's ,the new elem still being pushed into the array?
Pls anyone could help , don't want to ask the teacher , it looks so simple ?

Comment: If you have a teacher, and most probably you also pay for it, ask him :) no shame

Comment: not able to reproduce the error

Comment: @brk Issue is, OP is checking in loop. So if you try to push an element that exists at say 2nd index, for first iteration, `(arr[i] == newElem` will fail and value will be pushed in array

Comment: Considering your logic, the small mistake you have done is that you are not looping through all the elements before pushing:

    `var arr=['a','b'];
    var newElem='c';
    function f(){
     var flag = false;
       for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
         if(arr[i] == newElem){ 
         flag = true; }     
       }
       if(!flag){
         arr.push(newElem);
       }
    }
    f();`

Comment: Thnks pavan for pointing out the flaw in the data flow.

Comment: I've run it in an html file & if the (return) is not within the first if-curly-brackets it doesn't seem to work properly while in a console.log environment it works both ways?

Comment: quirimmo!  We have a school break here Down-under currently.

Answer (score 0):

Check if element exists first like so:

```
const arr = ['a', 'b'];
const newElem = 'c';
if (arr.indexOf(newElem) === -1) {
  arr.push(newElem);
}
```

Comment: `array.indexOf() === -1` is more appropriate as you do not want the matched value

Comment: Yeah... Nice ... Updated

Comment: Thanks Melas , could you  show the full code ?

Comment: You welcome. Thats the full thing there. Or you can explain what u mean by full code

Comment: Thanks Rajesh , you're right ,I wonder why they teach us this ancient for-loop?